# Create Nested Lists from excel files using For loop in R

Tags: r, excel, for-loop, nested-lists

I have several excel files (*.xlsx) and each file has many sheets. I want to create a nested list from each file. Although I can do it individually for each file by using the following code.

```
    g1 <- file1 %>%
  excel_sheets() %>%
  set_names() %>%
  map(read_excel, path = file1)
```

However, if I have to create some 5 nested lists `g1, g2, g3, g4, g5` for 5 excel files. Then I have to write the above code 5 times for each variable. Can we use `for loop` to iterate over `list.files` so that number of lines be reduced.

I need nested lists because I would merge them at a later stage.

I made a crude attempt as follows:

```
files <- list.files(pattern = "*.xlsx")

for (i in 1:length(files)){
  "g"[i] <- files[i] %>%
  excel_sheets() %>%
  set_names() %>%
  map(read_excel, path = files[i])
}
```

But this does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perhaps it will be useful

```
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)
path <- here::here("source", "xlsx")
list_files <- fs::dir_ls(path)

tibble(files = list_files) %>% 
  mutate(sheets = map(files, excel_sheets)) %>% 
  unnest(sheets) %>% 
  mutate(data = map2(files, sheets, read_xlsx))
```

Comment: thanks, I am able to get most from the code `tibble` onwards. But the output I am not sure if it is a nested list.

Comment: it worked by adding `unnest(data)` thanks.

Comment: Great! If you believe this answer was helpful for you, you could accept it by clicking the tick on the left side of this answer :)